# std::stringstream as parameter to a function

Tags: c++, stringstream, boost-bind

I have a `std::vector<std::string> temp_results` and I wish to use std::for_each to go through this vector and concatenate a string, so I concocted the following construction:

```
std::stringstream ss;
std::string res = std::for_each(temp_results.begin(), temp_results.end(), boost::bind(addup, _1, ss));

std::string addup(std::string str, std::stringstream ss)
{
    ss << str;
    ss << ";";

    return ss.str;
}
```

I get the following error, which is beyond my understanding:

```
error C2475: 'std::basic_stringstream<_Elem,_Traits,_Alloc>::str' : forming a pointer-to-member requires explicit use of the address-of operator ('&') and a qualified name
        with
        [
            _Elem=char,
            _Traits=std::char_traits<char>,
            _Alloc=std::allocator<char>
        ]
```

Could someone please explain what is wrong?

Comment: Maybe it's better if you pass the `stringstream` by reference.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If, by writing `return ss.str;` you intend to call the `str` member function from `std::stringstream`, then you are missing a pair of parenthesis :

```
return ss.str();
```

Also, your code probably won't do what you expect. If you want every call to `addup` to work on the same `std::stringstream` instance, you have to take it by reference : modify the `addup` signature and add a `boost::ref()` around the `ss` parameter in the `boost::bind`.

Here is a working version which I presume does what you expect :

```
void addup(std::string str, std::stringstream &ss)
{
    ss << str;
    ss << ";";
}

int main() 
{
    std::vector<std::string> temp_results;
    /* ... */

    std::stringstream ss;
    std::for_each(temp_results.begin(), temp_results.end(), boost::bind(addup, _1, boost::ref(ss)));
    std::cout << ss.str() << std::endl;
}
```

An alternative using `boost::lambda` :

```
std::for_each(temp_results.begin(), temp_results.end(), ss << boost::lambda::_1 << ';');
```

Comment: that's fixed, however now it says boost::bind cannot take stringstream as param 3, there is no such overload for bind???